# Firebase Element May not exist on a call, iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, information-retrieval

I am using firebase database and storage to hold images and their descriptions. At the moment I have it coded to have 8 Images and 8 Descriptions. I am trying to work out how to get it so that if a user only selects4 pictures and puts in 4 descriptions that it allows that to be called back. It works fine with 8 but when I add 4 only and select that table to be called it crashes with an error that the 5th photo var doesn't hold anything.

below is the code I am using to call the data for the table and where it crashes.

```
func configureCell(post: Post) {
    self.post = post
    self.carImages = []

    if post.imageUrl1 != "" {
        self.carImages.append(post.imageUrl1)
    }
    if post.imageUrl2 != ""{
        self.carImages.append(post.imageUrl2)
    }
    if post.imageUrl3 != "" {
        self.carImages.append(post.imageUrl3)
    }
    if post.imageUrl4 != "" {
        self.carImages.append(post.imageUrl4)
    }
    if post.imageUrl5 != "" {
        print ("Tony: \(post.imageUrl5)")
        self.carImages.append(post.imageUrl5)
    }
    if post.imageUrl6 != "" {
        self.carImages.append(post.imageUrl6)
    }
    if post.imageUrl7 != "" {
        self.carImages.append(post.imageUrl7)
    }
    if post.imageUrl8 != "" {
        self.carImages.append(post.imageUrl8)
    }
```

and the crash happens on imageUrl5

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class Post {




private var _imageUrl1: String!
private var _imageUrl2: String!
private var _imageUrl3: String!
private var _imageUrl4: String!
private var _imageUrl5: String!
private var _imageUrl6: String!
private var _imageUrl7: String!
private var _imageUrl8: String!

private var _postKey: String!
private var _postRef: DatabaseReference!
private var _photoInfo1: String!
private var _photoInfo2: String!
private var _photoInfo3: String!
private var _photoInfo4: String!
private var _photoInfo5: String!
private var _photoInfo6: String!
private var _photoInfo7: String!
private var _photoInfo8: String!




var profileImageUrl: String {
    return _profileImageUrl
}

var imageUrl1: String {
    return _imageUrl1
}
var imageUrl2: String {
    return _imageUrl2
}
var imageUrl3: String {
    return _imageUrl3
}
var imageUrl4: String {
    return _imageUrl4
}
var imageUrl5: String {
    return _imageUrl5
}
var imageUrl6: String {
    return _imageUrl6
}   
var imageUrl7: String {
    return _imageUrl7
}   
var imageUrl8: String {
    return _imageUrl8
}


var postKey: String {
    return _postKey
}



var photoInfo1: String {
    return _photoInfo1
}
var photoInfo2: String {
    return _photoInfo2
}
var photoInfo3: String {
    return _photoInfo3
}
var photoInfo4: String {
    return _photoInfo4
}
var photoInfo5: String {
    return _photoInfo5
}
var photoInfo6: String {
    return _photoInfo6
}
var photoInfo7: String {
    return _photoInfo7
}
var photoInfo8: String {
    return _photoInfo8
}

init(imageUrl1: String, imageUrl2: String, imageUrl3: String, imageUrl4: String, imageUrl5: String, imageUrl6: String, imageUrl7: String, imageUrl8: String, photoInfo1: String, photoInfo2: String, photoInfo3: String, photoInfo4: String, photoInfo5: String, photoInfo6: String, photoInfo7: String, photoInfo8: String) {


    self._imageUrl1 = imageUrl1
    self._imageUrl2 = imageUrl2
    self._imageUrl3 = imageUrl3
    self._imageUrl4 = imageUrl4
    self._imageUrl5 = imageUrl5
    self._imageUrl6 = imageUrl6
    self._imageUrl7 = imageUrl7
    self._imageUrl8 = imageUrl8

    self._photoInfo1 = photoInfo1
    self._photoInfo2 = photoInfo2
    self._photoInfo3 = photoInfo3
    self._photoInfo4 = photoInfo4
    self._photoInfo5 = photoInfo5
    self._photoInfo6 = photoInfo6
    self._photoInfo7 = photoInfo7
    self._photoInfo8 = photoInfo8

}

init(postKey: String, postData: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
    self._postKey = postKey



    if let imageUrl1 = postData["imageUrl1"] as? String {
        self._imageUrl1 = imageUrl1
    }
    if let imageUrl2 = postData["imageUrl2"] as? String {
        self._imageUrl2 = imageUrl2
    }
    if let imageUrl3 = postData["imageUrl3"] as? String {
        self._imageUrl3 = imageUrl3
    }
    if let imageUrl4 = postData["imageUrl4"] as? String {
        self._imageUrl4 = imageUrl4
    }
    if let imageUrl5 = postData["imageUrl5"] as? String {
        self._imageUrl5 = imageUrl5
    }
    if let imageUrl6 = postData["imageUrl6"] as? String {
        self._imageUrl6 = imageUrl6
    }
    if let imageUrl7 = postData["imageUrl7"] as? String {
        self._imageUrl7 = imageUrl7
    }
    if let imageUrl8 = postData["imageUrl8"] as? String {
        self._imageUrl8 = imageUrl8
    }


    if let photoInfo1 = postData["photoInfo1"] as? String {
        self._photoInfo1 = photoInfo1
    }
    if let photoInfo2 = postData["photoInfo2"] as? String {
        self._photoInfo2 = photoInfo2
    }
    if let photoInfo3 = postData["photoInfo3"] as? String {
        self._photoInfo3 = photoInfo3
    }
    if let photoInfo4 = postData["photoInfo4"] as? String {
        self._photoInfo4 = photoInfo4
    }
    if let photoInfo5 = postData["photoInfo5"] as? String {
        self._photoInfo5 = photoInfo5
    }
    if let photoInfo6 = postData["photoInfo6"] as? String {
        self._photoInfo6 = photoInfo6
    }
    if let photoInfo7 = postData["photoInfo7"] as? String {
        self._photoInfo7 = photoInfo7
    }
    if let photoInfo8 = postData["photoInfo8"] as? String {
        self._photoInfo8 = photoInfo8
    }

    _postRef = DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.child(_postKey)

}
}
```

[image: Crash at 5th Image]

[image: Firebase Data]

Comment: Obviously _imageUrl5 is nil or invalid but the code included in the question doesn't provide enough context. How is _imageUrl5 populated? Where is your Firebase code? What's the structure look like?

Comment: Thanks for your response @jay, imageUrl5 isn't populated in this example when a user only pics 4 images it doesn't create a html address to the photos for number 5 it only create one if more 5 photos are picked. this is what I need to work out. if Firebase doesn't have an imageUrl5 to populate in my code then how can i check to see if its nil or doesn't exist so that it doesn't try to populate it. if i try to use if imageUrl5 != nil but i get a warning that a non optional string check for nil will always return true. Ive updated my codes above to show more

Comment: If you define a variable to be required *private var _imageUrl1: String!* then it can never be nil. If it's optional *private var _imageUrl1: String?* then it can be and it can be tested for  nil in a variety of ways.

Comment: Hi I have now updated the code for you this is the whole post class

Comment: I updated the answer with a couple more options to check out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps an answer via an example

We have a post class with a private var that's optional - meaning it could contain a value or could be nil. This is indicated with the String?

When the external imageUrl1 is accessed it may return a value or may be nil, again the ? indicates that.

```
class Post{
    private var _imageUrl1: String?

    var imageUrl1: String? {
        return _imageUrl1
    }

    init(url: String?) {  //this could be nil!
        self._imageUrl1 = url
    }
}

let aPost = Post(url: "testUrl")

if aPost.imageUrl1 != nil {
    print(aPost.imageUrl1!)
}

//or the preferred way which unwraps the optional automatically
if let aPostUrl = aPost.imageUrl1 {
    print(aPostUrl)
} else {
    print("it was nil")
}

//here's a nil example
let bPost = Post(url: nil)
if let bPostUrl = bPost.imageUrl1 {
    print(bPostUrl)
} else {
    print("it was nil")  //prints it was nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this @jay. With your second comment I had worked out that i was using ! instead of ? but i had a problem with where to add the second? the error was giving me the option of unwrapping it in the post class which obviously wouldn't of worked. I do appreciate your time and patience with me on this and this solved a couple of days extra headache, I had tried a few things but this guidance helped a lot not only solve the problem but also you thought me something i need to be aware of more and that is invaluable to me. Thank you so much!